# Run stored procedures in InMemory unit tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

How do I run stored procedures in an in-memory databases? I am trying to search for this functionality.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

This is for setup:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFProviders.InMemory;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
    }
}

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Find_searches_url")
                .Options;

// Insert seed data into the database using one instance of the context
using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
{
    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/cats" });
    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/catfish" });
    context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com/dogs" });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The bottom line is that SProcs are a server thing, not an EF thing.  You can test stored procedures either via integration tests in C# or using an integration test directly on the server.

Comment: was trying to setup multiple in memory db items, so I didn't have test in physical locations, we needed to run multiple teardown and setup seed operations for our testnig

Comment: You have to realise that Entity Framework is not SQL Server.  It's a framework that can communicate with many different database back ends.  There are MS-SQL, MySql, or as you have found InMemory.  Your code is translated into whatever 'language' the back end requires.  SProcs are nothing to do with EF.

Comment: That's not something you should be using a stored procedure for anyways. Do the test setup in code. If you need to share that, you can create a helper class or use something like `IClassFixture` in xUnit.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer; the in-memory provider can't do it.

I had the same issue; I had stored procs surfacing in unit tests and I needed to mock the results. After searching for a library to do it and finding none that could do the big 3 (`FromSql`, `ExecuteSqlCommand` and Queries) I wrote my own: [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing). It uses the in-memory provider for most things and provides mocks for the bits it can't do.